# javascript: access function in closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the name of a function in a variable, but everything is within a closure. With this variable I want to call the function, something like this

```
(function(func) {
      this[func]() ;         // doesn't work

      function bar() {}
      function foo() {}
})('bar') ;
```

Is something like this possible or should I, for example, add the functions to a variable, like

```
(function(func) {        
      var ns = {
          bar: function() {},
          foo: function() {}
      };

      ns[func]() ;         // OK
})('bar') ;
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kirill Makes perfect sense. How do you call `foo` or `bar` in the first example using a "variable function" name? E.g. `window[foo]()` works fine in the global scope, `this[foo]()` doesn't.

Comment: `this` inside the closure is nothing else but `window` object. You'd better use the second approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variables and functions declared in the current lexical scope cannot be accessed by name using `[]` syntax - only property keys (per your second example) can be looked up dynamically based on the contents of another variable.

The only way around this is to resort to `eval`, which is almost never a good idea.

An exception applies for variables and functions declared in the global scope - those are actually properties of `window`.

Comment: ... Half-true. See my answer.

Comment: @svidgen in your answer you have not declared a lexically scoped function, you have added a property to an object.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you can't create lexically scoped variables/functions in an object? Or that the logical leap from exposing a lexical "member" is too great? ...

Comment: no, I'm saying that your answer doesn't appear to be remotely relevant.  The OP wanted to call a _lexically scoped_ function _by name_ from within that scope, where the name itself is a variable.  It can't be done without `eval`.

Comment: or by using property names, per his second code block.

Comment: @svidgen There's no half-truth here... exposed in your answer or otherwise.

Comment: The precise statements here are true. But, the *intended implication* is that the only feasible solution is to `eval()` or attach those functions to an explicitly named object. And that's *not* true. You can treat the whole block as one, big, anonymous object. ... Why this is so controversial is utterly baffling ...

Comment: the bit that's controversial is your apparently unwarranted assertions about how your method is so much better than the OP's trivially understood code.  And my answer says _nothing_ (implied or otherwise) about an explicitly named object.  The properties could just as easily have been attached to `this` as you did, but there's no discernible benefit in doing so.

Comment: @Alnitak Again, your failure to acknowledge the benefit(s) does not equal a lack of benefit(s). And the `this` in my answer is an anonymous object. Without the instantiation, `this` is `window` .. which defeats the purpose of the closure.

Comment: I guess I can only take the assertion that my code isn't equally, if not more, "travial" to understand as a complement ...

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, putting a function inside a closure is one way of declaring it "private" - such that *nothing outside can access it*. Furthermore, it's worth looking at the way code is minified:

Before:

```
(function() {
    function privateFn(var1, var2) {
        //TODO
    }
    return {
        publicFn: function() { }
    }
})();
```

After:

```
(function() {
    function _a(_0, _1) {

    }
    return {
        publicFn: function() { }
    }
})();
```

Notice how `privateFn` doesn't really exist anymore? The minifier knows, by definition of the language, that nothing can access that function outside - by name, or otherwise. You seem to want to make one of your functions public.

Comment: OP wants to access the function from inside the closure.

Comment: @dystroy He still got a point there. If he minifies his code, it will break because the minifier won't "rename" his string.

Comment: @Derija93 minification and strings as property keys don't mix, you have to tell the minifier which functions not to rename.

Comment: @Alnitak That's true and definitely something Katana314 should have mentioned.

Comment: @Derija93 in any event, a minifier won't touch the name of properties, so for lexically scoped variables it doesn't matter because the only way to access them using a variable-as-name is using `eval`.

Comment: @Alnitak That... really depends on the minifier you are using. Most common minifiers probably do exactly what you described, but just in case you've ever played with the advanced mode of Google's Closure Compiler: you'll really need to tell it what not to rename by means of annotations - or use the bracket notation on objects. Nothing you'll want for small projects...

Comment: @Derijla93: None of the minifiers I've touched ever work that way. Maybe it's buried in options somewhere, but something tells me that's for a good reason. I even wonder if it would break some of the core functionality of the libraries my company tends to use...here, we're basically aware of the fact that object notation is assigning a string key to a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
(new function() {
    this.a = function(x) {
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += x;
    }
})['a']('boom.');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CT4du/1/

A closure keeps everything private. And normally, `this` in a closure just refers to the `window`. But, you can "publicize" items in a "closure" without polluting the global space by turning it into an anonymous object first. This allows you to make one *and only one* method call on the object before it vanishes ...

You can do normal object things, like use private, lexical variables and expose only the methods you want exposed.

```
(new function() {

    var a = function(x) { document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += x; }
    var b = function() { a(d); }
    var c = function() { /* ... */ }
    var d = "whatever";

    // expose two of them .. 
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;

})['a']('boom.');
```

Comment: The link with the question isn't clear.

Comment: @dystroy What do you mean?

Comment: This is the best answer, I was writing the same answer until you posted. It does exactly what the OP needs. +1

Comment: @dystroy My solution does the same thing in effect, differing only slightly in synatx -- using `[func-name]()` on the "outside" instead of the inside -- incidentally providing far more flexibility, in my opinion.

Comment: your code provides no advantage over the OP's second proposed code block, which works perfectly.

Comment: @Alnitak It yields greater flexibility. Direct access to an anonymous object -- which admittedly may or may not be desired.

Comment: It's effectively an object literal with an added option for hidden members. I'd posit it's not only the easiest way to do it, it's the right way.

Comment: @svidgen I don't understand where this "yields greater flexibility"... In both cases you'll need to create an object, the only difference being that you either use `this` or `ns`. I think, in 3 months the `ns` approach is much easier to understand. Please explain, maybe I can learn something. ;)

Comment: @svidgen I disagree.  The OP's second code block is perfectly understandable, and could trivially be extended to include some lexically scoped variables, and all without needing to remember to call `new` to allow use of `this`.  Like Derija93, I think his version is simpler, and it's _just as flexible_!

Comment: oh, and `this` in a closure can be (and often is) any variable - `this` depends on how the closure is _invoked_.  Only in an IIFE would it _default_ to `window`.

Comment: @Derija93 If the intention is to `return ns`, they're no different, with the exception of the returned object having a `constructor` -- admittedly useful only if you at some point decide you want to pass the returned object around and replicate the ... err ... "closureish" thing. (Or if you want to pass the object around and eventually check it's "type")

Comment: the OP didn't want to return anything, he just wanted to call one of the named functions.

Comment: @Alnitak And you're suggesting this solution doesn't allow that?

Comment: sigh, no.  I'm *still* suggesting that your solution is no better (and is in fact more complicated) than the code the OP posted.

Comment: @Alnitak Except for the reasons I mentioned, of course. Namely, greater flexibility, control, and a distinct object "type" identity (probably not useful to the OP, but a notable difference!).

Comment: nope, none of those apply.  You're *way* overthinking this.  EOD.

Comment: @Alnitak You're confusing "none of those apply" with "I don't see how those apply" or possibly "this is above my head."

Comment: @svidgen Do you have any article on your proposition? I still don't see how this is more flexible. As Alnitak already said, the OP never intended to return `ns`. He is passing in a string used to invoke a function within the closure, he doesn't even want that function's returned value. As far as I see, the two codes simply have different objects. Barely any advantages or disadvantages in this scenario, the one simply looks more complex than the other. That's why I'm asking whether you have any in-depth tests or articles to support your thesis. I'd like to understand...

Comment: @Derija93 "Barely" != the "none" that's been shoved down my throat here. Nor should "it's impossible to do what you want" ever be a more acceptable answer than, "here's how you can better simulate what you want." ... Folks gotta stop harassing other folks for no good reason. What's the value in it? ... The solution works. And it has advantages, however minimal they may appear.

Comment: @svidgen if I'm not mistaken, you started it...

Comment: Admittedly, the two biggest advantages here simply "being able to think of the whole closer as an object" and "the end result is an 'typed' object that can either be ignored or handled further." And it's a **working** variation on the OP's examples. ... Did I mention **it works!?**

Comment: @Alnitak If by "started" you mean "harassed", you're mistaken. If by "started" you mean "pointed out that your answer is a bit misleading" ... yes. I "started" it ...

Comment: no-one else appears to think my answer is misleading.  You read something into it that isn't there.

Comment: @Alnitak So ... jump down my throat? Or ... ask why it seems misleading. ... Yeah. Jump down my throat was definitely the right solution.

Comment: @svidgen I finally see what you mean by "more flexible". Just in case the OP decides to further use the "closure" somewhere else, like calling a second function, he could easily do that by assigning it to a variable. Still I think this isn't too much of an advantage since you could also at any time give that function a name. Then I'd rather think that it's easier to treat the "closure" as an entire object and simply use `this.func_abc` rather than `function abc... return { abc : abc }`, but not really that much simpler. I would rather take this as an alternative, tbh.

Comment: You maybe should have stated that in your answer, could have spared some serious debate...ish thing which may even have resulted in this question being closed.