# I can't find an event listener and its handler but it exists

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener, userscripts

On a site I am trying to access a function inside a userscript to call it with a custom argument except I can only find it by typing on Chrome's console the following :

```
getEventListeners(window).keydown[0].listener
```

[image]

or by looking at the event listeners directly on the section under the HTML document on Chrome
[image]

This function comes from a script which can be found in the sources here:

[image]

Does anybody know how can I access that function?

Here is the client.js: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GodWoold/code/master/client.js
and the function I am looking for is located line 157 and you can find it by searching for:

```
b(b){++q.di;q.Mi=a;q.tj();a.Sf(b);q.tj();--q.di}
```

Comment: Access for what reason? What's the end goal here? Knowing that we might be able to tell you if it's even possible

Comment: @evolutionxbox the goal is to be able to trigger that function with a custom argument

Comment: It really depends on how the handler is defined in client.js...

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited my post and added these information

Comment: It looks like it's in a closure. I don't think you can reference it directly. Maybe you'll need to attach your own handler?

Comment: what does a closure means, I can't access this function directly?

Comment: @evolutionxbox attaching my own handler won't be possible as I don't know how that function really works

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure first and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722489/javascript-access-function-in-closure

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, I read those, is there any way to get that variable out of the closure or do you know if i can modify the script before it executs on the website?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16722552/989920 - no I don't think so